How to rewrite a Fourier transform after scaling the coordinates in spatial domain
Let $f$ be a function defined on an $n$-dimensional torus with side length $L$, which I denote $\Lambda^n_L$, and let its Fourier transform be
$$\tilde{f}(k) = \frac{k}{\langle k, k\rangle}e^{-\frac{k^2}{\alpha^n}} \tag{1}$$
for some fixed $\alpha > 0$. I would like to find a number $\gamma$ so that scaling each side of the torus by $\gamma$ gets rid of the $\alpha^n$ in the exponential. In other words I would like to scale $\Lambda^n_L$ to get $\Lambda^n_{\gamma L}$ in the spatial domain.
My first thought was to let $\gamma = \alpha$. By the scaling properties of the Fourier transform this gives
$$\tilde{f}(k) = \gamma^{-n}\frac{k/\gamma}{\langle k/\gamma, k/\gamma\rangle}e^{-\frac{(k/\gamma)^2}{\alpha^n}} = \alpha^{-n}\frac{k/\alpha}{\langle k/\alpha, k/\alpha\rangle}e^{-\frac{(k/\alpha)^2}{\alpha^n}} = \alpha^{-n-1} \frac{k}{\langle{k, k \rangle}}e^{-\frac{k^2}{\alpha^{n+2}}}. \tag{2}$$
I would like to rewrite this in terms of the coordinates of the scaled torus $\Lambda^n_{\gamma L} = \Lambda^n_{\alpha L}$ so let $$x' = \gamma x = \alpha x$$ and thus by the scaling properties of the Fourier transform $$k' = \gamma^{-1} k = \alpha^{-1} k \implies k = \alpha k'. \tag{3}$$
But substituting (3) into (2) to rewrite the scaled version of $\tilde{f}$ in the coordinate system $k'$ on $\Lambda^n_{\alpha L}$ undoes the scaling. I see what I'm doing wrong since I'm just applying the inverse transform of the one I just did, but how do I do this correctly?
